# Ionic 3, ion-col content has to align middle

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a tabular design from which two ion-col in a ion-row have different number of lines. but I need to align both the content in the middle. what would be best solution for this?

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
       ....other cols....
       <ion-col col-6>
        <label>Date of Audit:
          <h2>01/30/18<br/>
          1:06:50<small>PM UTC</small></h2>
        </label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6 text-center center class="overall-score">
        <label>Overall Score:
          <h1>40%</h1>
        </label>
      </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: You mean vertical middle? Or horizontal center?

Comment: vertical please

Answer (score 1):

Create a new css class:

```
.align-text-middle {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

And add that class to the ion-col.

Comment: Sorry August, align-items-center is not working for ion-col.

Answer (score 1):

The style need to be applied to the ion-col, in order to center its content.

CSS:

```
ion-col {
  text-align: center;
}
```

or

HTML:

```
<ion-col class="someclass">
```

CSS:

```
ion-col.someclass {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add ion-row

```
<ion-col>
  <ion-row style="min-height:100%" justify-content-center align-items-center>
    <p>test</p>
  </ion-row>
</ion-col>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Grids, rows and cols** for good practices, read the [Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/grid), simple and effective.

For center with this:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row justify-content-center>
    <h1>This is center</h1>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: This has been updated to ```<ion-row align-items-center>```

Comment: No, you aren't right. 'align-items-center' is use for vertical align on the center, on the other hand 'justify-content-center' is for horizontal align. Thx.

Comment: justify-content-center doesn't work for me on latest version of ionic; why else would I post this?  For fun?

Comment: Sorry if my message seemed sharp. If I post this is because worked me and all my team. We've done a project with Ionic 4 ( and Angular 7, but this doesn't matter), and this works. If you want I can post an example for you. But make sure you have put it like the example, without cols, only one grid and one row, and the content inside the row with justify-content-center should centered. Sorry for my bad english. Let me know if you get it. Thanks.